# Nginx main domain requests getting forwarded to subdomain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to set up an angular app and a dotnet core web api on the digitalocean server. I have successfully configured the setting for these two ( at least I believe I did ). However there is this one problem - all the request whether that be maindomain.xyz or api.maindomain.xyz - every requests are handled by the api.maindomain.xyz configuration.

Is this an intended behaviour ? If its not, could you help me find a solution?

Here is the nginx configuration.

---

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# sudo nginx -T                                                                                                
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok                                                                                                       
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful                                                                                                     
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:                                                                                                                            
user www-data;                                                                                                                                                         
worker_processes auto;                                                                                                                                                 
pid /run/nginx.pid;                                                                                                                                                    
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;                                                                                                                             

events {                                                                                                                                                               
        worker_connections 768;                                                                                                                                        
        # multi_accept on;                                                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                      

http {                                                                                                                                                                 

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.maindomain.xyz.conf:                                                                                            
server {                                                                                                                                                               
        listen 80;                                                                                                                                                     
        server_name api.maindomain.xyz;                                                                                                                           
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                      

server {                                                                                                                                                               
        listen 443;                                                                                                                                                    
        server_name api.maindomain.xyz;                                                                                                                           

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.xyz/fullchain.pem;                                                                             
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.xyz/privkey.pem;                                                                               

        ssl on;                                                                                                                                                        
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;                                                                                                               
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                                                                                                                          
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;                                                                                          
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;                                                                                                                                  

        gzip  on;                                                                                                                                                      
        gzip_http_version 1.1;                                                                                                                                         
        gzip_vary on;                                                                                                                                                  
        gzip_comp_level 6;                                                                                                                                             
        gzip_proxied any;                                                                                                                                              
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml ap
lication/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;                                                                                                                                 
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;                                                                                                                                            
        gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;                                                                                                                           

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;                                                                                                                         

        location / {                                                                                                                                                   
                proxy_pass            https://localhost:5001;                                                                                                          
                proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                                                                                
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                                                                              
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;                                                                                                              
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;                                                                                                                         
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                      
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                         
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                      

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/maindomain.xyz.conf:                                                                                                
server {                                                                                                                                                               
        server_name maindomain.xyz;                                                                                                                               
        listen 80;                                                                                                                                                     
        listen [::]:80;                                                                                                                                                
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;                                                                                                                   
        root /var/www/html;                                                                                                                                            
        index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                   
        location ~* \.(?:html|js)$ {                                                                                                                                   
                expires -1;                                                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                      


server {                                                                                                                                                               
        listen 443 ssl;                                                                                                                                                
        listen [::]:443 ssl;                                                                                                                                           
        root /var/www/html;                                                                                                                                            
        index  index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                   
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.xyz/fullchain.pem;                                                                                       
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.xyz/privkey.pem;                                                                                     
        location ~* \.(?:html|js)$ {                                                                                                                                   
                expires -1;                                                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

---

Removed some configuration for brevity.

Comment: Why have to put ipv6 listen address only in maindomain.xyz.conf?

Comment: @akshay202 Missed. I added that in the api.maindomain.xyz conf, however, did not make any difference in behaviour.

Comment: `server_name maindomain.xyz;` is missing from the last server block (listening on 443)

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks, this solved the issue. Could you please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the last `server` block, where `server_name` is missing.

This block should contain the following, for example below the `listen` lines:

```
server_name maindomain.xyz;
```